# Can I add a delay in between 'click' and 'addClass' in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I add a delay before the addClass method?

This doesnt seem to be working for me.

```
$("#btn").click(function doStuff(){
    $("#myoBj").show();
    $("#myoBj").animate({left: "15"});
    $(".secondObj").delay(1000).addClass('glow');
    $(".thirdObj").addClass('topGlow');
)};
```

Thanks

Comment: Use setTimeout() instead.

Comment: `delay` only works with animation methods (by default). `addClass` is not an animation method. It's always good to actually [**read the documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/): *"The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited — it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay — `.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#btn").click(function doStuff(){
    $("#myoBj").show();
    $("#myoBj").animate({left: "15"});

    setTimeout(function () {
        // Wait 1 second and add the class
        $(".secondObj").addClass('glow');
    }, 1000);

    $(".thirdObj").addClass('topGlow');
});
```

Comment: Cheers campari, very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—`.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   `setTimeout` function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Therefore `.delay()` is not a substitute for JavaScript's `setTimeout()`.

---

Use this:

```
$("#btn").click(function doStuff(){
    $("#myoBj").show();
    $("#myoBj").animate({left: "15"});
    setTimeout(function(){ $(".secondObj").addClass('glow'); }, 1000);
    $(".thirdObj").addClass('topGlow');
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not using the [jQuery `delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function, as the action needs to be on the animation queue (or, "an" animation queue, if you define one) for that to work; use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) instead:

```
setTimeout(function() { /* */ }, timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) method's callback to fire your code after the delay completes.

```
$("#btn").click(function doStuff(){
    $("#myoBj").show();
    $("#myoBj").animate({left: "15"});
    $(".secondObj").delay(1000).queue(function() {
          $(this).addClass('glow');
    });
    $(".thirdObj").addClass('topGlow');
)};
```